# The app crashes in iOS 4.1+, but successfully works in 4.0

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, tesseract

I have an application, which uses some 3rd party libraries, for example Tesseract library.
The application was developed in Xcode 3 with an SDK 4.0 and worked perfect.
But a few days ago I've decided to upgrade my Xcode and SDK. So I've installed XCode 4.0.2 with SDK 4.3.
Sure, after an upgrade I've rebuilded all the dependent libraries including Tesseract using the SDK 4.3. There were no errors during build. Everything was the same like it was during the build under SDK 4.0.
But when I run the app under simulator (4.1, 4.2, 4.3) I've got the following error:

**Detected an attempt to call a symbol in system libraries that is not present on the iPhone:
fopen$UNIX2003 called from function _ZN9tesseract15TessdataManager4InitEPKci in image APP_NAME.
If you are encountering this problem running a simulator binary within gdb, make sure you 'set start-with-shell off' first.**

I also tried it under device with ios 4.3, where the app simply crashes at the same place.

But the app continues to successfully work under simulator/device 4.0.

Does anybody knows what the issue is and how i can make my app runable under ios 4.1+?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close the question.

All the libraries for iphone simulator should be build with -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 option.